# Join and sum values in a SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to achieve this: I have a view in SQL Server 2012, and the result set is like this:

```
id sku  quantity  fieldtax  tax2
--------------------------------
1  2607   1        10         7
2  2607   2        10         7
3  55612  5         7        15
```

I would like to make the result set look like this:

```
id sku  quantity  fieldtax  tax2
---------------------------------
1  2607   3        10        7
3  55612  5         7       15
```

I need to sum the columns that have the same `sku` - how can I achieve this?

I already try this is the full table:

```
SELECT
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.id,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.TransactionType,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.TransactionModifier,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.SKU,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.Tax1,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.Tax2,
    SUM(VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.Quantity) AS QUANTITY,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.Tax3,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.TransactionNumber
FROM 
    dbo.VENTAS_AGRUPADAS
GROUP BY 
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.id,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.TransactionType,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.TransactionModifier,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.SKU,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.Tax1,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.Tax2,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.Tax3,
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.TransactionNumber
ORDER BY 
    VENTAS_AGRUPADAS.SKU DESC
```

Thank you

Comment: So why did the `fieldtax` for 55612 change to 20?

Comment: and the id change from 3 to 2

Comment: SUM(quantity) is easy, but what to do with fieldtax and tax2?

Comment: thats wrong, was just for example

Comment: that will be fixed, i just revised the example

Comment: Now that your sample is fixed this is just a basic SUM. What have you tried?

Comment: i tried to sum quantity but what to do with sku?

Comment: You would group by sku. From your new query what about it is not working correctly? Just saying it doesn't work doesn't really say what the problem is.

Comment: well i just removed ID and now is working good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this, if fieldtax and tax2 always will be the same for an sku:

```
select sku, SUM(quantity), fieldtax, tax2
from tablename
group by sku, fieldtax, tax2
```

Or this, for each sku, sum quantity, and take average for fieldtax and tax2:

```
select sku, SUM(quantity), AVG(fieldtax), AVG(tax2)
from tablename
group by sku
```

Comment: i tried the first one but not working, still not count refering the column sku

Comment: i dont need to filter by sku too?

Answer (score 1):

You need a combination of SUM and GROUP BY.

```
SELECT id, sku, SUM(quantity) as quantity, SUM(fieldtax) as fieldtax, tax2 FROM tabla GROUP BY sku;
```

Looking at your query, you're grouping by too many different columns, no good can come from that. Only group by the columns that can have a repeated value among different rows, like the sku as you were saying.